# Can malware on Ubuntu be transferred after re-install?

Tags: malware

I had a pop-up virus, so I just thought I'd rather re-install instead of resetting browser and wondering if the malware is still there, but did the malware get formatted when I re-installed Ubuntu? The only thing I see that's weird is at night when I'm on my PC it looks like more than one tab is open but when I open my eyes wide enough they all of a sudden close, and nothing unusual shows in my history.

Comment: So since I installed this Ubuntu over the last Ubuntu it's gone?

Comment: But why wouldn't it be removed if the hard drive was formatted?

Comment: I didn't sync anything though. I use Firefox.

Comment: Yeah... I needed to download a video off a website and got a pop-up. I don't know if it's me being tired at night or what, but for a second every once in awhile it looks like more than one tab is open then just closes.